# 17.10 & HP MicroServer Gen10 (AMD Opteron X3216) amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_temperature was not implemented

Tags: 17.10, amdgpu

I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my HP MicroServer Gen10 which runs an AMD Operton X3216 APU.

I notice that /var/log/syslog is full of the following:

> Nov 10 16:08:08 homenas kernel: [32966.191478] amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_temperature was not implemented.
>
> Nov 10 16:08:13 homenas kernel: [32971.195243] amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_fan_speed_percent was not implemented.
>
> Nov 10 16:08:13 homenas kernel: [32971.195272] amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_fan_control_mode was not implemented.
>
> Nov 10 16:08:13 homenas kernel: [32971.195421] amdgpu: [powerplay] pp_dpm_get_temperature was not implemented.

This is a pretty minimal installation, can anyone advise what's going on and how I can resolve?

Thanks

Comment: That message went away when I switched to Linux 4.17-rc1 mainline kernel on 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I get these messages when I run Psensor. One of the temperature readings doesn't show anything in Psensor, I'm guessing that is what is causing the messages.